# Bash manual input and shift of positional parameters

Tags: bash, function, parameters, shift, getopts

(Briskly, this question concerns mainly how to apply information to `getopts` and how to apply a `shift` to a manually-defined array.

I'm writing a procedure for the start of some Bash functions that parses parameters for a function in the usual `getopts` way while *also* parsing *unexpected* parameters (by looping over `getopts` processing multiple times).

In the code below can be seen a little function `process_arguments()` which essentially contains the `getopts` processing and a concluding `shift` operation which acts on the positional parameters. Because this overall procedure for parameter parsing is destined for *functions* as opposed to scripts, I'd like to move the processing contained in the function `process_arguments` to the main `while` loop in the script. This involves a modification to the input and output information from the procedure in the function.

The input information for the `getopts` processing can be passed to `getopts` in the array `args`:

```
getopts optstring name [args]
```

However, I'm not sure of how the output of the procedure can be changed. At present, it shifts the positional parameters and then it prints the positional parameters (`echo "${@}"`).

So, questions...

- Is this `getopts` `args` approach the right way to pass information to the procedure?
- How can I apply the `shift` to the parameters that are passed to `getopts` and how can I then output these shifted parameters to the rest of the script's processing?

Thanks for your help. I welcome any other guidance. The overall goal is to remove the function `process_arguments()` and incorporate its functionality into the main ``while``` loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
#
# This is a test of command line parameter parsing that is explicitly non-POSIX.
# This approach handles
#     - options (for getopts)
#     - arguments of options (for getopts)
#     - positional arguments (for getopts) and
#     - non-option arguments (command line parameters not expected by getopts).
# All non-option arguments are placed in the string non_option_parameters. The
# silent error reporting mode of getopts is required. Following command line
# parameter parsing, input information can be accepted based on internal
# priority assumptions.
#
# example usage:
#     ./script.sh 
#         non-option parameters:
#     ./script.sh  -a Dirac
#         -a triggered with parameter Dirac
#         non-option parameters: 
#     ./script.sh -a Dirac -b
#         -a triggered with parameter Dirac
#         -b triggered
#         non-option parameters: 
#     ./script.sh -a Dirac Feynman -b
#         -a triggered with parameter Dirac
#         -b triggered
#         non-option parameters: Feynman 
#     ./script.sh -a Dirac Feynman Born -b
#         -a triggered with parameter Dirac
#         -b triggered
#         non-option parameters: Feynman Born 
#     ./script.sh -a Dirac Feynman Born Born -b
#         -a triggered with parameter Dirac
#         -b triggered
#         non-option parameters: Feynman Born
#     ./script.sh -a Dirac Feynman Born Born -b
#         -a triggered with parameter Dirac
#         -b triggered
#         non-option parameters: Feynman Born Born
#
################################################################################

process_arguments(){
    OPTIND=1
    while getopts "${option_string}" option; do
        case ${option} in
            a)
                echo "-a triggered with parameter "${OPTARG}"" >&2 # output to STDERR
                ;;
            b)
                echo "-b triggered" >&2 # output to STDERR
                ;;
            \?)
                echo "invalid option: -"${OPTARG}"" >&2 # output to STDERR
            ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $(expr ${OPTIND} - 1)
    echo "${@}"
}

option_string=":a:b"
non_option_parameters=""
parameters="${@}"
while [ ! -z "${parameters}" ]; do
    parameters="$(process_arguments ${parameters})"
    non_option_parameters="${non_option_parameters} "$(awk -F '[ \t]*-' '{print $1}' <<< "${parameters}")
    parameters=$(awk -F '[ \t]*-' 'NF > 1{print substr($0, index($0, "-"))}' <<< "${parameters}")
done
echo "non-option parameters:${non_option_parameters}"
```

Comment: Why not just use `OPTIND`? Incrementing `OPTIND` before invoking `getopts` will cause `getopts` to start with the next argument.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't spend a lot of time reading your code. I agree with you: do your options processing at the script's "main level" so you can work directly with the script's position parameters.

Here's a rewrite:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":a:b" option; do
    case $option in
        a)
            echo "-a triggered with parameter $OPTARG" >&2
            ;;
        b)
            echo "-b triggered" >&2
            ;;
        :)
            echo "missing argument for option -${OPTARG}" >&2
            ;;
        \?)
            echo "invalid option: -${OPTARG}" >&2
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

echo "remaining arguments:"
for (( i=1; i<=$#; i++ )); do
    printf "%d: '%s'\n" $i "${!i}"
done
```

And in action:

```
$ bash ./opts.sh -a A -b B -c -d "foo bar" baz
-a triggered with parameter A
-b triggered
remaining arguments:
1: 'B'
2: '-c'
3: '-d'
4: 'foo bar'
5: 'baz'
```

You don't see any "invalid option" errors for "-c" and "-d" because the `while getopts` loop ended when it hit the first non-option argument "B".

---

Update: calling getopts multiple times:

```
extra_args=()

while (( $# > 0 )); do
    OPTIND=1
    while getopts ":a:b" option; do
        case $option in
            a) echo "-a triggered with parameter $OPTARG" >&2 ;;
            b) echo "-b triggered" >&2 # output to STDERR ;;
            :) echo "missing argument for option -$OPTARG" >&2 ;;
            ?) echo "invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2 ;;
            esac
    done
    shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))
    if (( $# > 0 )); then 
        extra_args+=( "$1" )
        shift
    fi
done

echo "non-option arguments:"
printf "%s\n" "${extra_args[@]}"
```

```
$ bash ~/tmp/opts.sh   -a A B -c -d "foo bar" baz -b
-a triggered with parameter A
invalid option: -c
invalid option: -d
-b triggered
non-option arguments:
B
foo bar
baz
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion. I like your coding, but I'm not sure we agree. I would want to be able to have the expected and unexpected parameters to 'intermingle'. So, something with the option string ":a:b" could be used like so ```./opts.sh -a A B -c -d "foo bar" baz -b``` and the option ```-b``` *would* be interpreted by ```getopts```, not simply by other procedures engaged after ```getopts``` halts when it sees something unexpected. If you check my code, you'll see that I'm using ```getopts``` multiple times in order to have this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The shiftless solution follows.

I use bash arrays to preserve positional (non-flag) parameters, because it's the only effective way to handle parameters with whitespace. In particular, your `echo "${@}"` effectively wipes flattens arguments, despite the quoting, because `echo` doesn't preserve quoting.

I also retain `process_argument`, although you could easily put it in the loop. It makes very little difference (and directly calling `exit 1` rather than `return 1` is arguably simpler.)

```
# process_argument option
# Do whatever needs to be done to handle provided option. Fail on error.
OPTIONS=:a:b
process_argument() {
  case "$1" in
    a)
        echo "-a triggered with parameter $OPTARG" >&2
        ;;
    b)
        echo "-b triggered" >&2 # output to STDERR
        ;;
    :)
        echo "missing argument for option -${OPTARG}" >&2
        return 1
        ;;
    \?)
        echo "invalid option: -${OPTARG}" >&2
        return 1
        ;;
  esac
}

# Loop to handle all parameters
non_option_parameters=()
while true; do
  while getopts "$OPTIONS" option; do
    if ! process_argument "$option"; then exit 1; fi
  done
  if ((OPTIND > $#)); then break; fi
  non_option_parameters+=(${!OPTIND})
  ((OPTIND++))
done

printf "Non-option parameters: "
printf "<%s> " "${non_option_parameters[@]}"; echo
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for - how to handle getopts args and operands in the same function. Brilliant!